# Upload Dockerfile to Google Cloud Services

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dockerfile

I just made a Google Cloud account, and i want to deploy my containerized flask application.

I reached the early instance creation phase, and i selected `Deploy a Container`.
However, there is no option to upload my Dockerfile.

There is only a dropdown.

[image]

So how can i upload a Dockerfile?

Comment: You deploy a container, not a file ;) You need to build the container before. Use cloud build for that `gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/<project-id>/containerName` and then use this path in this field!

Answer (score 3):

You can’t upload your image directly in that way, you need to upload it first to your [Container Registry](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry). 
To push any local image to Container Registry using Docker or another third-party tool, you need to first tag it with the registry name and then push the image.

[Tag the local image with the registry name](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/pushing-and-pulling#tag)

- To tag an image:

Verify that you have configured [authentication](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication) to Container Registry.

- Choose a hostname, which specifies location where you will store the image.
  (`gcr.io` hosts images in data centers in the United States, but the location may change in the future)
- Choose an image name, which can be different from the image's name on your local machine.
- Combine the hostname, your Google Cloud Console project ID, and image name:

```
HOSTNAME/PROJECT-ID/IMAGE
```

- Tag the local image with the registry name by using the command:

```
docker tag SOURCE_IMAGE HOSTNAME/PROJECT-ID/IMAGE
```

where `SOURCE_IMAGE` is the local image name or image ID.

[Push the tagged image to Container Registry](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/pushing-and-pulling#push_the_tagged_image_to)

- Push the tagged image to Container Registry by using the command:

```
docker push HOSTNAME/PROJECT-ID/IMAGE
```

This command pushes the image that has the tag latest.

When you push an image to a registry that does not exist yet in your project, Container Registry creates a storage bucket.

- To view the image you pushed:

Go to the [Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr) to view the registry and image.

Run `gcloud container images list-tags` to view the image tag and the automatically-generated digest:

```
gcloud container images list-tags HOSTNAME/PROJECT-ID/IMAGE
```

The command's output is similar to the following:

```
DIGEST        TAGS        TIMESTAMP
44bde...      test        2017-..-..
```

I have reproduce it in my own project and I was able to create the VM instance using my own image.

When you have done the steps above you will be able to see your image in your Container Registry.
And if you click the name of the image you will see something like
[image]

Then you can use this URL `gcr.io/>>MY-TEST-PROJECT<</myapp28032021` with the full repository name to create your instance.

Additionally, if you click the name of the image you will be able to **Deploy** it directly to **Cloud Run, GCE and GKE**.
[image]

Comment: Thank you. I reached a point. But i got this `unauthorized: You don't have the needed permissions to perform this operation, and you may have invalid credentials. To authenticate your request, follow the steps in: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication`. So i have an authentication problem (as you mentioned) that i am trying to solve. However, it's not really straightforward from the docs.

Comment: I used that URL you already sent [Authentication methods](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication#methods) I tried some of them but not all of them worked for me, I used [gcloud method](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication#gcloud-helper) I think it is the easiest one,  take in consideration that you can use Cloud Shell or Cloud SDK to use this method

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to set up the authentication, using the links you sent me, but i cannot figure out what i should select for the `KEY-FILE` parameter. I posted a separate question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67471276/google-cloud-authentication-getting-the-key-id-of-my-app

Answer (score 1):

For that you need to have an image in GCR(Google Container Registry). This link will help to pull and push images from GCR.

https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/pushing-and-pulling