# Google Cloud Authentication - getting the Key ID of my app

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to push a docker image to the Container Registry, so that my app can utilize it.

In order to do that, i have to set up Authentication.

This requires using a command like:

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account ACCOUNT --key-file=KEY-FILE
```

This is mentioned here:
https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication#gcloud-helper

But i first have to set up service account keys, as mentioned here:
https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys#creating_service_account_keys

I did everything that link said, and i got the json file.

But what exactly is the KEY-FILE parameter?

There is no mention on what the KEY-FILE parameter is.

Answer (score 1):

In the Key-file Parameter you basically need to provide your service account Json file which you have created and downloaded locally to your system which contains a private key.

so basically it will look like

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account Name-of-Your-Service_account --key-file name of the serviceaccount json file.
```

Example-

```
$gcloud auth activate-service-account test-account@temp123.iam.gserviceaccount.com --key-file myservice.json
```

Comment: Thanks but how do i pass it? I mean, when i generated the key, it downloaded a json file to my machine. But i use gcloud on the browser. So what exactly do i pass?

Comment: you can refer to this public documentation -  https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/activate-service-account

Comment: I refered to it, but no noew information is presented. I did everything that my second link said and the file is downloaded locally. But i have Cloud Shell and no files exist there (except the standard README.txt).

Comment: @user1584421 - You will need to upload the service account JSON file to Cloud Shell and then execute your command in Cloud Shell. Note: Cloud Shell already has credentials (your user account) so you do not need another service account.

Comment: @JohnHanley How exactly do i upload the JSON file to Cloud Shell? (btw this is a lame policy since i downloaded the file from them, now i have to upload it back to them). I tried to use it locally by downloading gcloud from a snap. Even then, i received `ERROR: (gcloud.auth.activate-service-account) Invalid value for [ACCOUNT]: The given account name does not match the account name in the key file.  This argument can be omitted when using .json keys.`

Comment: @JohnHanley Is there a doc on how to upload my json file?

Comment: @user1584421 Yes, read the Google Cloud Shell documents. There is a section on uploading files.

Answer (score 1):

@user1584421 KEY-FILE is the physical location of the json file you have generated.

Lets say - C:\my-key.json

Comment: I know. i provided the whole path, and it did not work.

Comment: What errors did you get? Did you generated a .json or .p12? Did you check if value for ACCOUNT and the value in the JSON file are same?

Comment: I have just checked the error in your previous command "Invalid value for [ACCOUNT]: The given account name does not match the account name in the key file", I think the account value you are providing in command is not the same as in the JSON file. Please open the JSON file and match once.

Comment: The only relevant field i found inside the json file is `client_id`. And it was only numbers. While what i typed in the arguments is letters. How come my json does not have my service account name?

Comment: Do you see client_email?  That's the account name

Comment: I know that is what i am using. The prompt from the cloud shell.